# What if I don't specify source and target version of java in maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

Anyone please tell me what is the default version of source and target version of java used by maven when its not specified in pom.xml

Comment: How is asking here faster than just trying it?  I believe the default is 1.5 but that may have changed.

Comment: Depends on the version of Marven theres a list here https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html

Comment: The default is `1.5` so I encourage users to define not only source/target better also all plugins to get a reproducible state..usually this should be done in a corporate parent....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven compiles with the maven compiler plugin. The default version is java 1.5 for source and target.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/